# How to add macros to the menubar in powepoint 2011(powerpoint for mac)?

Tags: macos, macros, ms-office, powerpoint

I have created macros in powerpoint 2011(powepoint for mac). I want to add this macro to the menubar. I am successfully able to do this in word 2011 but in the powerpoint when I go to View >Toolbars >Customize Toolbars and Menus > Toolbars and Menus(tab), in the categories I am not able to find the macros.

Please let me know the solutions or any input that helps to add macros to the menubar.

Thank you !!

Comment: You need to do this in an Add-in that adds menu/toolbar items.  This page on my PPT FAQ site explains the basics:  it may take a bit of adaptation for Mac vs Windows, but give it a try for starters, let us know how you make out:  Create an ADD-IN with TOOLBARS that run macros 
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00031_Create_an_ADD-IN_with_TOOLBARS_that_run_macros.htm